# MongoDb c# mapping recursive object with bsonextraelements

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have following classes:

```
public class Property
{ 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public IDictionary<string, Property> OtherData { get; set; }
} 

public class Device
{
   public string DeviceId { get; set; }
   public IDictionary<string, Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

What i want to achieve in json and map to those classes, is:

```
{  
   "DeviceId":"asd",
   "Properties":{  
      "PropertyA":{  
         "Description":"some info",
         "PropertyAB":{  
            "Description":"some info",
            "Value":"etc"
         }
      },
      "PropertyB":{  
         "Description":"some info",
         "Value":"etc"
      }
   }
}
```

So, as you can see, i want to map concrete Model "Property" in recursive way with ExtraElements usage. But above code will fail, as BsonExtraElements can be used only i IDicionary interface. 
Also:

```
public class Property : IDictionary<string, Property>
{ 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

doesn't work. And to be honest, this semantic would be the most desired. (no need to reach extra Property OtherData) 
But neither both of those semantics i cannot map properly.
Is anyone tried something similar before? Any hints how to achieve this?